# Is there any way to identify the current Encore app environment (local/test/production)?

Tags: go

I'm building an [Encore](https://encore.dev) app and am trying to define different behavior for my local and test environments in an easy way. I want to avoid triggering some actions for testing, that should run in prod.

Any ideas for how to best go about this?